# the package linux-firmware does not install...see below.please help

Tags: apt, dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -f install linux-firmware
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  amd64-microcode intel-microcode iucode-tool
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-firmware
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1800 not upgraded.
36 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/27.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 50.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  linux-firmware
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
(Reading database ... 355777 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-firmware (from .../linux-firmware_1.79.18_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.18_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/usbduxfast_firmware.bin', which is also in package firmware-linux-free 3.3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.18_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
apt-get autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-firmware but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Answer (score 0):

You installed some custom `linux-firmware-free` package that conflicts with `linux-firmware`.

You can fix it by

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-firmware-free
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `aptitude install linux-firmware` - it will offer you some options of solving that dependency problem.

NOTE:
`apt-get -f install` is to be used without any package, as a separate command. You can try`apt-get -f install; apt-get -f install linux-firmware` but not `apt-get -f install linux-firmware`. Of course use `sudo` accordingly.

Comment: im using root....ive tried all those commands...i had upgraded my kali release to 3.14...there seems to be a linux-firmware package installed automatically via the update command that cant either be overwritten or cant delete.

Comment: for kali linux it would be probably better to ask at distro's forum: https://forums.kali.org/
there might be a bug in package in their repo which has to be resolved by kali packages maintainers.